# C++11: literal 7 is a prvalue?

Tags: c++, c++11

I came across this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/lvalues-and-rvalues-visual-cpp?view=vs-2019#:%7E:text=Examples%20of%20prvalue%20expressions%20include,accessible%20only%20by%20the%20compiler.).  And its example says:

```
int main()
{
    int i, j, *p;

    // Correct usage: the variable i is an lvalue and the literal 7 is a prvalue.
    i = 7;
...
}
```

I wonder why literal 7 is a prvalue.

The standard [7.2.1.1.2] says:

```
A prvalue is an expression whose evaluation
initializes an object or a bit-field, or computes the value of an
operand of an operator, as specified by the context in which it
appears, or an expression that has type cv void.
```

The expression `7` itself doesn't initializes an object nor a bit-field, nor computes the value of an operand of an operator as `7` itself doesn't have an operator.

Maybe I don't interpret the standard correctly.

Comment: Doesn't 7 initialise `i`?

Comment: Also, you're referring the worst doc ever. 7 is a `prvalue`, which is clearly mentioned in this [good](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category) article

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 it does.  but the comment refers to the expression `7` alone not `i = 7;`.  For example, we won't say the expression `j` in `i = j;` is an prvalue for sure, right?

Comment: isn't j an lvalue?  as it has an identity?

Comment: @HCSF the expression j in i = j; is lvalue by https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.id.unqual#2.sentence-7 "The expression is an lvalue if the entity is a [...] variable"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard quote you used describes the properties of prvalues, but does not define them. The definitions are scattered through the standard (and gathered [on cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category)).

The definition for your situation is found in [[expr.prim.literal]/1](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.literal#1.sentence-3):

> A string-literal is an lvalue, a user-defined-literal has the same value category as the corresponding operator call expression described in [lex.ext], and **any other literal is a prvalue**

Answer (score 1):

> The expression `7` itself doesn't initializes an object nor a bit-field

Actually it does, it initializes the `7` object. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category

> #### prvalue
>
> The following expressions are prvalue expressions:
>
> - a literal (except for string literal), such as `42`, `true` or `nullptr`;
>   ...

Comment: What's the definition of `object` in C++ standard?  I always thought it referred to something non literal.  The examples [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object) don't mention anything about literal.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  The post is related to `int` variables not a literal like `7`.   juanchopanza in the comment section pointed out few fallacies in the answer.

Comment: Indeed, there are other answers on this question providing more details, and more importantly the link to more formal documentation on the matter.